# Cannot start service api: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "python manage.py runserver

Tags: python, django, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I would like to running docker-compose.
during running react and django application, docker-compose returns the following error:

```
(base) dominik@Precision:~/PycharmProjects/humanet-docker$ ls
api  docker-compose.prod.yml  docker-compose.yml  front  nginx
(base) dominik@Precision:~/PycharmProjects/humanet-docker$ docker-compose ps
              Name                             Command                State                                     Ports                                 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
a7c8de30f648_humanet-docker_api_1   python manage.py runserver ...   Exit 127                                                                         
humanet-docker_db_1                 docker-entrypoint.sh postgres    Up         5432/tcp                                                              
humanet-docker_front_1              docker-entrypoint.sh yarn  ...   Up         0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp,:::3000->3000/tcp                              
humanet-docker_nginx_1              /docker-entrypoint.sh ngin ...   Up         0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp,:::443->443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp,:::80->80/tcp
humanet-docker_pgadmin_1            /entrypoint.sh                   Up         443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5050->80/tcp,:::5050->80/tcp                         
(base) dominik@Precision:~/PycharmProjects/humanet-docker$ docker-compose up
humanet-docker_pgadmin_1 is up-to-date
humanet-docker_front_1 is up-to-date
Starting a7c8de30f648_humanet-docker_api_1 ... 
humanet-docker_nginx_1 is up-to-date
Starting a7c8de30f648_humanet-docker_api_1 ... error

ERROR: for a7c8de30f648_humanet-docker_api_1  Cannot start service api: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown

ERROR: for api  Cannot start service api: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
(base) dominik@Precision:~/PycharmProjects/humanet-docker$
```

below docker-compose.yml file from my docker

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  front:
    build: ./front
    working_dir: /home/dominik/node
    env_file: ./front/.env.dist
    volumes:
      - ./front:/home/dominik/node
      - /private/etc/ssl:/etc/ssl
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    restart: always
    tty: true
  api:
    build: ./api
    working_dir: /home/dominik/python
    command: pip install -r requirements.txt && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./api:/home/dominik/python
      - /private/etc/ssl:/etc/ssl
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
      - 8445:8445
    restart: always
    tty: true
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - /private/etc/ssl:/etc/ssl
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    working_dir: /home/dominik/node
    restart: always
    tty: true
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment: 
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: xxx
      POSTGRES_USER: xxx
      POSTGRES_DB: xxx
      POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
      PGDATA: /data/db
    volumes:
      - /home/dominik/data/humanet-db:/data/db
  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    restart: always
    environment: 
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: xxx
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: xxx
    ports:
      - 5050:80
    volumes:
      - /home/dominik/data/humanet-pgadmin:/var/lib/pgadmin
      - /home/dominik/data/humanet-pgadmin/servers.json:/pgadmin4/servers.json
```

it is first time when docker returns my that message:
Cannot start service api: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown

ERROR: for api  Cannot start service api: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

how to deal with it?

Comment: What's in your image's Dockerfile?  (Does it have an `ENTRYPOINT` that's ignoring the `command:` override; do you need a `command:` override at all; why do you need to re-run `pip install` every time you start the container?)

Answer (score 4):

Based on the error message

```
exec: "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
```

It looks like you've passed the command and it's args as a single field for docker to run. E.g. if your Dockerfile contains:

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000" ]
```

That will look for the full string as the executable to run, not python with the first arg manage.py, but an executable named something like

```
/bin/"python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
```

Instead you'd need to separate each of these arguments:

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000" ]
```

Then you get to the next issue of why you are setting the command in your compose file and if you need that.

Answer (score 0):

Try give executable permission in yous entrypoint.sh and docker-entrypoint.sh files with the command `chmod +x` before run docker-compose command.